# Filtering data to one daily point per individual

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a dataset containing information about certain individuals for many different dates.
What I want is to filter my data to only have one row of data per date, *per individual*.

I know how to filter it so there's just one data point per overall date, but not how I can limit the data per individual to just have one point per day.

```
    ID       Date     Time            Datetime      Long    Lat       Status
    305 2022-02-12  4:30:37 2022-02-12 04:30:00 -89.71239 48.00947    MN
    305 2022-02-12  0:00:37 2022-02-12 00:00:00 -89.71250 48.00948    MN
    306 2022-02-12  4:30:37 2022-02-12 04:30:00 -89.71239 48.00947    MN
    306 2022-02-12  0:00:37 2022-02-12 00:00:00 -89.71250 48.00948    MN
    306 2022-04-06  4:30:37 2022-04-06 04:30:00 -89.71239 48.00947    MN
    306 2022-02-12  0:00:37 2022-02-12 00:00:00 -89.71250 48.00948    MN
```

Would then become

```
    ID       Date     Time            Datetime      Long    Lat       Status
    305 2022-02-12  4:30:37 2022-02-12 04:30:00 -89.71239 48.00947    MN
    306 2022-02-12  4:30:37 2022-02-12 04:30:00 -89.71239 48.00947    MN
    306 2022-04-06  4:30:37 2022-04-06 04:30:00 -89.71239 48.00947    MN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date) %>% 
  summarise_all(first)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID Date       Time    Datetime             Long   Lat Status
#>   <int> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1   305 2022-02-12 4:30:37 2022-02-12 04:30:00 -89.7  48.0 MN    
#> 2   306 2022-02-12 4:30:37 2022-02-12 04:30:00 -89.7  48.0 MN    
#> 3   306 2022-04-06 4:30:37 2022-04-06 04:30:00 -89.7  48.0 MN
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(305L, 305L, 306L, 306L, 306L, 306L), Date = c("2022-02-12", 
"2022-02-12", "2022-02-12", "2022-02-12", "2022-04-06", "2022-02-12"
), Time = c("4:30:37", "0:00:37", "4:30:37", "0:00:37", "4:30:37", 
"0:00:37"), Datetime = c("2022-02-12 04:30:00", "2022-02-12 00:00:00", 
"2022-02-12 04:30:00", "2022-02-12 00:00:00", "2022-04-06 04:30:00", 
"2022-02-12 00:00:00"), Long = c(-89.71239, -89.7125, -89.71239, 
-89.7125, -89.71239, -89.7125), Lat = c(48.00947, 48.00948, 48.00947, 
48.00948, 48.00947, 48.00948), Status = c("MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", 
"MN", "MN")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This works perfectly Allan, thank you.

So if I understand correctly, summarise_all(first) will return all your data, but it will only return the first value of Date per ID?

If so, how does the first line of code specify you want Date per ID, and not ID per date?

Comment: @Treebeard aren't these the same thing? It groups by both, which means each group is each unique combination of ID and date. It selects the first of that group. If there are three individuals on the same date, you'll get three rows. If there are 3 dates with one individual, you will still get three rows. It will only remove rows if both dates and ID are duplicates

Comment: One more question, does this also work with POSIXct or POSIXt data (the Datetime column)? The last thing I need to do is filter the data to keep only data where there's at least one point per 48 hours, for at least 365 days, per ID (so if we have data over 3 years for a certain ID, only keep data where there's at least 182 data points within consecutive 365 days, dismiss other data from this ID). This seems like a little more complex...

Comment: @Treebeard no, it will remove duplicate date / id combinations only. If you used date times instead of dates, it would only remove duplicate datetime/ID combos